# Firebase In-App Messaging (iOS) - Only receiving after fresh install

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I recently added Firebase In-App messaging.
The installation seems to be working fine but I have an issue with testing the messages.

I create a "Campaign" with a test message, and on the state option I get "on_foreground" and "app_launch".
I assume that "on_foreground" means that users will see the message when entering on re-entering the app.

But when I try the test campaign, I don't see any messages on my device. However if I delete the app and reinstall, Then I am able to close/open the app and receive the test message then.

Anyone else having any similar issues ?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Do you get any solution? If yes, please share it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase In-App Messaging only retrieves messages from the server once per day. Also, there's a Per-device frequency limit. By default, a campaign is not shown again after it has been impressed or viewed by the user within a day.

If you wish to test campaign on demand without hitting the limit, follow the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=ios#send_a_test_message).